# Not navigating to other view controller, When passing bundle is nil in iOS?

Tags: ios6

I just want to navigate from one view controller to another view controller using....>

PhoneDialer *phoneDialer = [[PhoneDialer alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhoneDialer" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:phoneDialer animated:YES];
  [phoneDialer release];

```
   But App is crashing on navigation in iOS6.(not in iOS7) in Xcode 5.1.1
```

Crash Report-->'-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'

Please Help me out....

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the viewDidload method of PhoneDialer you are appending some string and that String is NUll that causes issue. Please check your viewDidLoad,viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods if you implement those you find the issue.